# Bootstrap: How to properly align several rows of col-xs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following code, which is basically a set of bootstrap callout tags.
I am trying to align several rows of 12 columns. If I use row I get an unwanted scroll bar inside the callout tag.

This is the code, which can be also checked in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59dLq0nc/1/)

```
<body style="width:100%;">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success" style="overflow:auto;">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x20" style="max-height: 48px; max-width: 60px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <h4>FOO</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small><em>Col 1</em></small></span><br/>
                    <span>10000</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 2</small></span><br/>
                    <span>20000</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 3</small></span><br/>
                    <span>30000</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Estado/</small></span><br/>
                    <span>Estado</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span>FOO &rarr;</span>
                    <span>BAR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success" style="overflow:auto;">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x60" style="max-height: 48px; max-width: 60px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                <h4>FOO</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <span><small><em>Col 1</em></small></span><br/>
                        <span>10000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <span><small>Col 2</small></span><br/>
                        <span>20000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <span><small>Col 3</small></span><br/>
                        <span>30000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>

                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <span><small>Estado/</small></span><br/>
                        <span>Estado</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <span>FOO &rarr;</span>
                        <span>BAR</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As shown, the first callout has an image which has not enough height to misalign the `col-xs`tags, but the second one has enough height so it misaligns the other `<div class="col-xs">`.

What should be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As per I understand you just need to add one div to `img` tag and give css to that div:

```
<body style="width:100%;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success" style="overflow:auto;">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <div class="demo-img">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x60" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <h4>FOO</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small><em>Col 1</em></small></span><br/>
                    <span>10000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 2</small></span><br/>
                    <span>20000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 3</small></span><br/>
                    <span>30000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Estado/</small></span><br/>
                    <span>Estado</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span>FOO &rarr;</span>
                    <span>BAR</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success" style="overflow:auto;">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="demo-img">
                      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x60" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <h4>FOO</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small><em>Col 1</em></small></span><br/>
                    <span>10000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 2</small></span><br/>
                    <span>20000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Col 3</small></span><br/>
                    <span>30000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <span><small>Estado/</small></span><br/>
                    <span>Estado</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span>FOO &rarr;</span>
                    <span>BAR</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And add below css to your .css file :

```
.demo-img {
  height: 48px;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.demo-img img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that does not fix anything, it breaks the alignment of both callouts and does not preserve image size (https://jsfiddle.net/59dLq0nc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use min-height of 48px.

```
img{
min-height:48px;
}
```

You can check in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rupalkataria/sksx7w9h/)

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap class="img-responsive" in your code.

Check code here in [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Rupalkataria/65uxmbjs/)

Comment: does not preserve image size.

Comment: but also use your css of height and width so it will preserve the size